# npm script to both build typescript files and run after deploying to AWS EB environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, npm

I want AWS EB to automatically build and run my files without me having to explicitly build everytime I push to git repo. I've tried placing this in "scripts" in package.json:

```
"start": "tsc build && node build/index.js"
```

The outDir specified in my tsconfig.json is `build`. This unfortunately didn't work and I get 'Degraded' health status. I know this is definitely the problem with my web server, because I tried manually building and placing `node build/index.js` in the "start" script, and it worked.
Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "woocommerce-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx tsc && node build/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config src/index.ts",
    "deploy": "npm run build && node build/index.js",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  }
}
```

And my simple app with a get path at home, and a post path at `/hook` to consume webhooks.

```
import express, { Response, Request } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import helmet from "helmet";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send({ message: "Hello world1234" });
});

app.post("/hook", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.status(200).send({ message: "success" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Which CI/CD service are you using?. I use aws codepipeline toghether with codebuild. You can implement the build step running npm run build and then specify the root folder. If you refer to this let me know and I can post a more detailed answer with the build spec.

Comment: @nacho I'm using CodePipline as well. I did try creating a buildspec file in the past and adding a build step using CodeBuild, but couldn't get it to work. Would greatly appreciate getting to see how you pulled it off! It's a bit of a nuisance having to manually build every time.